# Catalog Price Rules - product prices are being reset automatically at midnight

Tags: catalog-price-rules

I am using Magento CE 1.8.1.0.
I set a few catalog price rules with not date range. 
After clicking "save & apply" rules are applied correctly.
But each night at about midnight all prices become regular again.

I commented  the catalogrule_apply_all job in the etc.xml file as I thought it's processing reset the prices, but prices were still reset.

Any idea which automatic process might reset the prices?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you mean `1.8.1.0`.

Comment: Can someone please point me to the duplicated question?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you should at least have a start date set, because whithout the rule is never going to be active with normal mechanics. Every night, when the prices are reindexed, it looks up if there are rule-based prices set for the next day. Because you do not have one set (the rule cannot figure out if it should be active because of NO date given at all) the normal prices are considered for price index. 
Using a start date AND reenabling catalogrule_apply_all (without the prices are not generated for the next day) should fix your issues.

Comment: This issue happens whether I set start date or not :(

Comment: Have you reenabled the catalogrule_apply_all cronjob ? If so then maybe you could take a look into catalogrule_products and see if your products have an entry for the estimated dates. catalogrule_prodcuts_price is for the real price that is valid for this product at a given timestamp