# Price Rules stopped working recently, reset every 48 hours, cron is running

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, cron

We have run this magento store for many years now on magento 1.4.x. We have an actual cron daemon run the cron.sh script every 5 minutes as is expected. the customer setup price rules that have been in place since the start. In the last few weeks we have run into an issue where the rules reset once every 48 hours at around midnight. This would tend to lead me to the cron, but it seems to be running. I tried changing it so it runs cron.php with the php binary, but that didn't seem to help it at all either. I am not sure why this has stopped working and i was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to how to track it down? I cannot find any errors in cron log, or messages log...I also looked into the magento exceptions and systems logs also, nothing there. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Have you installed any new extensions lately? You should check the cron entries in all of your local & community extensions to see if any of them are set to midnight and also check if they could have any effect of your price rules.

Comment: We have not added or changed anything thats the odd thing, it just stopped randomly. We regularly install OS patches for CentOS, but im not sure what out of those would affect this issue that wouldn't break the website completely.I do see one module has a job that looks like it goes off at 00:00. Ill try delaying it by say 10 minutes. Thats the only one though.

Comment: Just found this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36597/catalog-price-rules-product-prices-are-being-reset-automatically-at-midnight

It looks like other people have had this same issue

Comment: or at least similar :)